# regex needed to match anything within p tags

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match anything that is within `<p>` tags so for example if I had some text:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

The regex would match the Hello world part

Comment: Which programming language? Maybe there's still a hope for you.

Comment: What if `<p>` tags are not properly balanced, as they usually (or at least very often) are?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in javascript:

```
var str = "<p>Hello world</p>";
str.search(/<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/)
```

in php:

```
$str = "<p>Hello world</p>";
preg_match_all("/<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/", $str);
```

These will match something as complex as this

```
< p style=  "font-weight: bold;" >Hello world  <  /  p >
```

Comment: Fails if there is a tag inside, as in `<p>I would like <b>all</b> the text!</p>`.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**: Don't do it. Just don't.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If you insist, use `<p>(.+?)</p>` and the result will be in the first group. It is not perfect, but **no regexp solution to HTML parsing problem will ever be.**

E.g (in python)

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('<p>(.+?)</p>')
>>> r.findall("<p>fo o</p><p>ba adr</p>")
['fo o', 'ba adr']
```

Comment: That matches the p tags aswell though I don't want the tags to be returned

Comment: Fails to match `<p >Spaces are valid in tags</p >`

Comment: MSalters is talking about spaces *in* the tags, not between them. ie: there's a space between the `p` and the `>`.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. yet another reason why you really should __NEVER__ try parse __ANY__ html with regexp. "#¤()%#=!"¤(=!"#¤! _Hmpf, I Should know this by now_

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the above proposed solutions will fail either:

- to return text within `<p>...</p>` tags whenever it contains other tags like `<a>`, `<em>`, etc.
  or
- to distinguish between `<p>` and `<path>` or
- to include tags with attributes like `<p class="content">`

---

Consider using this regex:

`<p(|\s+[^>]*)>(.*?)<\/p\s*>`

Resulting text will be captured in group 2.

---

Obviously, this solution won't work properly whenever closing tag `</p>` will be for some reason enclosed in comment tags `<p> ... <!-- ... </p> ... -->`

Comment: This really is the most complete answer to the OP.  Should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Nice solution! I think just about every other proposed solution will fail if there is a <path> tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in Python as a comprehensive solution:

```
import re
import bs4
import requests

page = requests.get(link)
page_content = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
result = page_content.find_all('p')
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

This will work for any pair of tags.

e.g `<p class="foo">hello<br/></p>`

The \1 makes sure that the opening tag matches the closing tag.

The content between the tags is captured in \2.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking into this Regex or any other regex to match specific HTML tags, this Regex below will work as needed:

```
<\s*p[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>
```

---

This will match strings like the below strings as mentioned in xzyfer's answer:

```
<p>I would like <b>all</b> the text!</p> < p style=  "font-weight: bold;" >Hello world  <  /  p >
```

---

Link to the Regex on Regex101 here: https://regex101.com/r/kjpLII

---

If you would like to use the Regex for other HTML tags instead of just `p` tags you can change the `p`'s  in the Regex to whichever HTML tag you wish to match:

```
<\s*div[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*div\s*>
```

Comment: You'll have problem with nested `<DIV>`.